# MVC 4 How to get json response from a repository into a view using Ajax?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, repository-pattern, getjson

I am a newbie when it comes to MVC4 Web Development and there's something I am struggling with.

Basically, I have the following :

```
public class maincontroller: Controller
{
    private MyRepository myRepository;

    public mainController()
    {
         myRepository= new MyRepository(); 
    }

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var mystuff = myRepository.GetPrograms();            
        return View(mystuff);
    }


    public ActionResult MyStuff()
    {
        var mystuff = myRepository.GetStuff(1);
        return Json(mystuff , JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
}
```

Assuming that in my `MyRepository' class I have two functions:

One that is setting up `mystuff':

```
 public MyRepository()
    {


        for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
        {
            programs.Add(new MyStuff
            {
                Title = "Hello" + i,
                content = "Hi"

            });
        }
    }


and second function that gets Stuff:
public List<MyStuff> GetStuff(int pageNumber = 0)
    {
        return stuff
            .Skip(pageNumber * pageCount)
            .Take(pageCount).ToList();
    }
```

All works well.  I mean I am able to iterate through `stuff' and display on a view...

The problem is that I want to display `MyStuff()` ( which returns Json ) using AJAX and then append all `stuff` to a view.  How do I do that?

I have been beating my head against the wall for about 4 hours now, and can't get this working.

Please any help will be much appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

At the most straightforward level, you can simply append HTML to your document using something like this (assuming you're using JQuery, because it's so much easier):

```
<div id="container"></div>

// make AJAX call to "MyStuff" action in the current controller
$.get(@Url.Action("MyStuff", function(data) {

    // cycle through each item in the response
    $.each(data, function(index, item) {

        // construct some HTML from the JSON representation of MyStuff
        var html = "<div>" + item.StuffProperty + "</div>";

        // append the HTML to a container in the current document
        $("#container").append(html);
    });
});
```

This adds some HTML for each item in the collection to a container element, using (eg) `StuffProperty` from the `MyStuff` class.

---

Appending HTML manually like this can be a hassle once it gets too complicated -- at that point you should consider using either:

1. Partial views (return HTML directly from the controller, instead of JSON)
2. A client-side templating engine like Mustache.js, Underscore.js, etc, to convert JSON into HTML.

Comment: Thanks @dbaseman for your quick response.  When I use `$.get(@url.Action("MyStuff"....`  I get errors with the intellisence telling me that `function does not exist in the current context.  Any thoughts?

Comment: I don't know if it's a bug or I am doing something wrong, but can't make the `$.get` code have  the `function(data) as a parameter.  Please help me.  I may have missed something.

Comment: @ito that probably means you haven't got JQuery loaded ... have to use `<script type='text/javascript' src='http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.8.3.min.js'></script>`, before the above script block.